# Javascript to read value from a text file and display in html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a html file copied below, where I am trying to set the password policy in a linux server. So, My question here is "on my web page if I click on 'password policy' link then it should read pwquality.conf file in Linux server and print the min and max values in the text area or the scroller should point to the value mentioned in the pwquality file. 
And in the end if I make any changes in the html page and click on submit then those values should get updated in the same file."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style all input fields */
input {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

/* Style the submit button */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the reset button */
input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the container for inputs */
.container {
  background-color: #6877a0;
  padding: 20px;
}
input[type=range] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;
width: 300px;
height: 20px;
  padding-top:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=range]:focus{
  outline:none;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position:relative;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -1px rgba( 0, 0,0.2),
    -25px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5),
    -75px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5),
    -125px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5),
    -175px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5),
    -225px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5),
    -275px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5),
    -325px 0 0 20px rgba(90, 184, 6, 0.5);
  z-index:2;
}
input[type="number"] {
    width: 65px;
    height: 20px;
}
input[type=number]:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.number-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#f1f1f1">

<h2 align= "center"><u>Password policy setting page</u></h2>
<div class="container" align = "center">
<form id="myForm" align="center">

   Expiry<br><input type="range" name="ExpiryRange" min="0" max="100" value="30" oninput="this.form.ExpiryInput.value=this.value" />
             <span class='number-wrapper'><input type="number" name="ExpiryInput" min="0" max="100" value="30" oninput="this.form.ExpiryRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /></span><br>
   Min.Length<br><input type="range" name="MinlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenInput.value=this.value" />
                 <input type="number" name="MinlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br>
   Max.Length<br><input type="range" name="MaxlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenInput.value=this.value" />
                 <input type="number" name="MaxlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br>
   Lowercase Letter<br><input type="range" name="LCRange" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.LCInput.value=this.value" />
                 <input type="number" name="LCInput" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.LCRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br>
   Uppercase Letter<br><input type="range" name="UCRange" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.UCInput.value=this.value" />
                 <input type="number" name="UCInput" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.UCRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br>
   Digit<br><input type="range" name="DRange" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.DInput.value=this.value" />
                 <input type="number" name="DInput" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.DRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br>
   Symbol<br><input type="range" name="SRange" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.SInput.value=this.value" />
                 <input type="number" name="SInput" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.SRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br>
     <br><br>
</form>
</div>
<div align="center">
<input type="Submit" align="center" onclick="alert('Success!!!')">
<input id="reset" onclick="resetFunc()" type="button" value="Reset">
</div>
<script>
function resetFunc(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
function checkLength1(elem) {
  if (elem.value > 100) {
    alert('Max value is 100')
    elem.value = '';
  }
}
function checkLength2(elem) {
  if (elem.value > 4) {
    alert('Max value is 4')
    elem.value = '';
  }
}
function readValue() {

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help.

Comment: What backend are you using,  Php, Node.js, ASP.net...etc.?

Comment: this is not possible in javascript (browser), since its client side. it cant read/write files

Comment: I am using javascript as backend.

Comment: The only backend Javascript I know is Node.js, is that what you mean.?

Comment: yes, it is Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, updated your tags to show `node.js`, as this is important information to help you.

So to answer your question, unfortunately it's not a simple answer.   There are multiple ways to communicate between client & server,  Rest API websockets etc.

The simplest to start with I would say is Rest API's, this link might help get you getting started ->  https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9

What I would do is first create simple REST api with a simple GET & PUT verb for your `pwquality.conf`, don't worry about the client part yet.  You can test this bit using utility's like POSTMAN https://www.getpostman.com/ or even `curl` if your a Linux guru.

Now there is also security to take care off here, you could implement this now or later.  If you just want to get things working first you can then do the next bit.

So you now have a simple REST API service going on your website, and you have tested the GET & PUT verbs work as expected. To now get your client using these verbs you can use either Ajax or the new `fetch` API that most browsers now have.  It's not difficult to do, but I would first get your GET / PUT working, and then maybe ask another question on SO on how to use `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API / `ajax` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

And finally, don't forget about security, especially if you plan on making your website open to the public.  Security is another big question, so you might be best asking another question on SO when you come to doing it.

And finally, you might find all this overwhelming to start with,.  Don't worry, just do it in stages as I've mentioned and you'll soon be up and running.

Comment: How can we achieve the same thing using PHP?

Comment: @CharanRaj  Pretty much the same, there is lots of information on creating Rest API's in PHP.   Again get your Rest API in PHP working, tested using something like Postman,.  Here is a link to get started, https://www.phpflow.com/php/create-php-restful-api-without-rest-framework-dependency/  If you google `PHP Rest API` there are more links & video's you could use.